# Can you break statements down using logic symbols?

Tags: logic

Can you break down complicated statements using symbolic logic notation?
For example if you have a statement:

> declaring the stimulus was p when it wasn’t was less common than indicating it wasn’t p when it was

can you somehow formalize it or simplify it using logic symbols.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would add a dummy variable in here.  The quote only speaks of "claiming p" and "was p," so it looks like p may be the variable needed.  However, implicit in the construction of that sentence is the idea that there are scenarios or cases or situations for which p could be claimed or true.  More specifically, there are *stimuli* for which p could be claimed true or be true.

I would define two functions, claimedP(s) and actuallyP(s).  They specify that, for any given stimulus "s," p was claimed to be true or p was actually true, respectively.  This gets us most of the way there.  We can translate large chunks of the phrase now.  "declaring the stimulus was p when it wasn't" can be rendered as a logical phrase,  claimedP(s) AND (NOT actuallyP(s)).  "indicating it wasn't p when it was" can be rendered as "(NOT claimedP(s)) AND actuallyP(s)

The remaining concept of "less common" is hard to render as pure logic unless one permits second order logic, which would allow us to define lessCommon(φ, ψ) as a function over two predicates which returns true if the stimuli where φ is true are less common than where ψ is true.

I think it would be more typical to render the concept of "less common" using mathematics other than logic.  Two approaches which I think are common would be set theory and probability theory.

In a set theoretic approach, one would have a set of stimuli, S.  One can then use the set construction notation {f(s), s∈S}, which is the set of all elements of S such that f(s) is true.  We can then use the cardinality notation |X|, which is the typical notation for the number of elements in a set and traditional integer definitions for <

|{claimedP(s) AND (NOT actuallyP(s)) | s∈S}| < |{(NOT claimedP(s)) AND actuallyP(s) | s∈S}|

One could also use a probabilistic approach.  In this, we have a random variable S, which represents a random stimulus (this contrasts with the above set theoretic approach, where S was a set).  We can speak to the expectation of a random variable, using the usual E[X] notation, to claim that the expectation of one random variable is less than another:

E[claimedP'(S) AND (NOT actuallyP'(S))] < E[(NOT claimedP'(S)) AND actuallyP'(S)]

In this, I had to tweak things slightly.  The original logical definition of claimedP and actuallyP had a stimulus as an argument.  For the probabalistic definition, we need them to accept a random variable of stimuli as an input, and output a random boolean variable.  To be explicit, I named these functions claimedP' and actuallyP'

There are certainly other approaches, but I think the second order logic approach, the set theoretic approach, and the probabilistic approach would account for the vast majority of ways people would choose to render that phrase as symbols.

Answer (score 1):

> There exists less cases “(claiming p) AND (p = FALSE)” than cases “(claiming
> not-p) AND (p = TRUE)”.

I did not formalize “to claim” and “less than”.

There exists a logical calculus to formalize “to believe”. It could be considered a candidate for formalizing “to declare”.

But I do not expect that quantitative statements like “less than” can be simplified by logic.

Answer (score 0):

What if a word usage or idiom was tied to a cartoon analysis.

What could a computer do there.

Alas, not much.

Thanks.

Comment: It is possible that even if cartoons presented a special interface that allowed them to be mined by AI systems, people, could, develop, ... their own, idioms.